# How to create a looping module that creates one window at a time per SQL row result?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, wxpython

I'm creating an IP Configuration program where in one part, I have to modify selected rows from my database to modify information into them.

In order for me to do this, I have to create a window at every row, then wait for the user to finish the input before the user presses next, and a new window will pop out and the old window would be Destroyed.

Here is the Code I have for the module:

```py
class moddtb(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, title, parent=None):
        global l_a
        t = len(l_a)
        self.n = 0
        self.b = 0
        while self.n<t:
            while True:
                wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=parent, title=title, size=(1100, 500))
                panel = wx.Panel(self)
                self.Centre(direction=wx.BOTH)
                self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.cls)
                print(self.n)
                mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM ip_config WHERE id=%s;", (l_a[self.n],))
                new_ip = mycursor.fetchone()
                self.n_id = str(new_ip[0])
                self.n_hn = str(new_ip[1])
                self.n_rl = str(new_ip[2])
                self.n_aut = str(new_ip[3])
                self.n_ali = str(new_ip[4])
                self.n_typ = str(new_ip[5])
                self.n_env = str(new_ip[6])
                self.n_isc = str(new_ip[7])
                self.n_sta = str(new_ip[8])
                self.n_vla = str(new_ip[9])
                self.n_ip = str(new_ip[10])
                self.n_pui = str(new_ip[11])
                self.n_gri = str(new_ip[12])
                self.n_idr = str(new_ip[13])
                self.n_sys = str(new_ip[14])
                self.n_aps = str(new_ip[15])
                self.n_das = str(new_ip[16])
                self.n_phs = str(new_ip[17])
                self.n_rac = str(new_ip[18])
                self.n_lom = str(new_ip[19])
                self.n_phm = str(new_ip[20])
                self.n_mod = str(new_ip[21])
                self.n_ser = str(new_ip[22])
                self.n_prv = str(new_ip[23])
                self.n_os = str(new_ip[24])
                self.n_war = str(new_ip[25])
                self.n_es = str(new_ip[26])
                self.n_el = str(new_ip[27])
                if self.n_hn is None:
                    wx.MessageBox('An error has been made, selected row %s is empty. Skipping to next row.' % (self.n_id), 'Creation Error', wx.OK | wx.ICON_ERROR)             
                    continue
                f1 = wx.Font(12, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, False, "Arial")
                f2 = wx.Font(18, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.FONTWEIGHT_BOLD, False, "Sergoe UI")

                ttllbl = TransparentText(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="Please fill out the information in this form:   ", pos=(60,27),
                                         size=(200,50), style=wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW, name='transparenttext')
                ttllbl.SetFont(f2)
                idlbl = TransparentText(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="ID: ", pos=(60,77),
                                         size=(50,50), style=wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW, name='transparenttext')
                idlbl.SetFont(f1)
                idtbx = wx.TextCtrl(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, value=self.n_id, pos=(150, 77), size=(180,25), style=wx.TE_READONLY)
                hnlbl = TransparentText(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="Host Name: ", pos=(60,107),
                                         size=(50,50), style=wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW, name='transparenttext')
                hnlbl.SetFont(f1)
                self.hntbx = wx.TextCtrl(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, value=self.n_hn, pos=(150, 107), size=(180,25))
                rolelbl = TransparentText(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="Role: ", pos=(60,137),
                                         size=(50,50), style=wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW, name='transparenttext')
                rolelbl.SetFont(f1)
                self.roletbx = wx.TextCtrl(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, value=self.n_rl, pos=(150, 137), size=(180,25))
                athlbl = TransparentText(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="Authorize: ", pos=(60,167),
                                         size=(50,50), style=wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW, name='transparenttext')
                athlbl.SetFont(f1)
                self.athtbx = wx.TextCtrl(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, value=self.n_aut, pos=(150, 167), size=(180,25))
                alslbl = TransparentText(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="Alias: ", pos=(60,197),
                                         size=(50,50), style=wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW, name='transparenttext')
                alslbl.SetFont(f1)
                self.alstbx = wx.TextCtrl(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, value=self.n_ali, pos=(150, 197), size=(180,25))
                typlbl = TransparentText(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="Type: ", pos=(60,227),
                                         size=(50,50), style=wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW, name='transparenttext')
                typlbl.SetFont(f1)
                self.typtbx = wx.TextCtrl(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, value=self.n_typ, pos=(150, 227), size=(180,25))
                envlbl = TransparentText(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="Enviroment: ", pos=(60,257),
                                         size=(50,50), style=wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW, name='transparenttext')
                envlbl.SetFont(f1)
                self.envtbx = wx.TextCtrl(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, value=self.n_env, pos=(150, 257), size=(180,25))
                isiplbl = TransparentText(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="ISCI IP: ", pos=(60,287),
                                         size=(50,50), style=wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW, name='transparenttext')
                isiplbl.SetFont(f1)
                self.isiptbx = wx.TextCtrl(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, value=self.n_isc, pos=(150, 287), size=(180,25))
                staiplbl = TransparentText(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="Static IP: ", pos=(60,317),
                                         size=(50,50), style=wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW, name='transparenttext')
                staiplbl.SetFont(f1)
                self.staiptbx = wx.TextCtrl(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, value=self.n_sta, pos=(150, 317), size=(180,25))
                vliplbl = TransparentText(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="VLAN: ", pos=(60,347),
                                         size=(50,50), style=wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW, name='transparenttext')
                vliplbl.SetFont(f1)
                self.vliptbx = wx.TextCtrl(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, value=self.n_vla, pos=(150, 347), size=(180,25))

                maniplbl = TransparentText(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="Management IP: ", pos=(360,77),
                                         size=(50,50), style=wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW, name='transparenttext')
                maniplbl.SetFont(f1)
                self.maniptbx = wx.TextCtrl(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, value=self.n_ip, pos=(500, 77), size=(180,25), style=wx.TE_READONLY)
                pubiplbl = TransparentText(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="Public IP: ", pos=(360,107),
                                         size=(50,50), style=wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW, name='transparenttext')
                pubiplbl.SetFont(f1)
                self.pubiptbx = wx.TextCtrl(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, value=self.n_pui, pos=(500, 107), size=(180,25))
                grpiplbl = TransparentText(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="Group IP: ", pos=(360,137),
                                         size=(50,50), style=wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW, name='transparenttext')
                grpiplbl.SetFont(f1)
                self.grpiptbx = wx.TextCtrl(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, value=self.n_gri, pos=(500, 137), size=(180,25))
                idriplbl = TransparentText(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="IDRAC IP: ", pos=(360,167),
                                         size=(50,50), style=wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW, name='transparenttext')
                idriplbl.SetFont(f1)
                self.idriptbx = wx.TextCtrl(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, value=self.n_idr, pos=(500, 167), size=(180,25))
                sysszlbl = TransparentText(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="System Size: ", pos=(360,197),
                                         size=(50,50), style=wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW, name='transparenttext')
                sysszlbl.SetFont(f1)
                self.syssztbx = wx.TextCtrl(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, value=self.n_sys, pos=(500, 197), size=(180,25))
                appszlbl = TransparentText(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="Application Size: ", pos=(360,227),
                                         size=(50,50), style=wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW, name='transparenttext')
                appszlbl.SetFont(f1)
                self.appsztbx = wx.TextCtrl(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, value=self.n_aps, pos=(500, 227), size=(180,25))
                dtszlbl = TransparentText(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="Data Size: ", pos=(360,257),
                                         size=(50,50), style=wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW, name='transparenttext')
                dtszlbl.SetFont(f1)
                self.dtsztbx = wx.TextCtrl(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, value=self.n_das, pos=(500, 257), size=(180,25))
                physzlbl = TransparentText(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="Physical Size: ", pos=(360,287),
                                         size=(50,50), style=wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW, name='transparenttext')
                physzlbl.SetFont(f1)
                self.physztbx = wx.TextCtrl(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, value=self.n_phs, pos=(500, 287), size=(180,25))
                rdconlbl = TransparentText(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="Raid Config: ", pos=(360,317),
                                         size=(50,50), style=wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW, name='transparenttext')
                rdconlbl.SetFont(f1)
                self.rdcontbx = wx.TextCtrl(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, value=self.n_rac, pos=(500, 317), size=(180,25))
                lgmemszlbl = TransparentText(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="Logical Memory \nSize: ", pos=(360,347),
                                         size=(50,50), style=wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW, name='transparenttext')
                lgmemszlbl.SetFont(f1)
                self.lgmemsztbx = wx.TextCtrl(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, value=self.n_lom, pos=(500, 347), size=(180,25))

                phymemszlbl = TransparentText(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="Physical Memory \nSize: ", pos=(700,77),
                                         size=(50,50), style=wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW, name='transparenttext')
                phymemszlbl.SetFont(f1)
                self.phymemsztbx = wx.TextCtrl(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, value=self.n_phm, pos=(840, 77), size=(180,25))
                mdllbl = TransparentText(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="Model: ", pos=(700,117),
                                         size=(50,50), style=wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW, name='transparenttext')
                mdllbl.SetFont(f1)
                self.mdltbx = wx.TextCtrl(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, value=self.n_mod, pos=(840, 117), size=(180,25))
                srlnumlbl = TransparentText(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="Serial Number: ", pos=(700,147),
                                         size=(50,50), style=wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW, name='transparenttext')
                srlnumlbl.SetFont(f1)
                self.srlnumtbx = wx.TextCtrl(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, value=self.n_ser, pos=(840, 147), size=(180,25))
                prvcpulbl = TransparentText(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="Processor/VCPU: ", pos=(700,177),
                                         size=(50,50), style=wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW, name='transparenttext')
                prvcpulbl.SetFont(f1)
                self.prvcputbx = wx.TextCtrl(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, value=self.n_prv, pos=(840, 177), size=(180,25))
                oslbl = TransparentText(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="OS: ", pos=(700,207),
                                         size=(50,50), style=wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW, name='transparenttext')
                oslbl.SetFont(f1)
                self.ostbx = wx.TextCtrl(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, value=self.n_os, pos=(840, 207), size=(180,25))
                wrtylbl = TransparentText(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="Warranty: ", pos=(700,237),
                                         size=(50,50), style=wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW, name='transparenttext')
                wrtylbl.SetFont(f1)
                self.wrtytbx = wx.TextCtrl(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, value=self.n_war, pos=(840, 237), size=(180,25))
                eoslbl = TransparentText(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="End of Support: ", pos=(700,267),
                                         size=(50,50), style=wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW, name='transparenttext')
                eoslbl.SetFont(f1)
                self.eostbx = wx.TextCtrl(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, value=self.n_es, pos=(840, 267), size=(180,25))
                eollbl = TransparentText(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="End of Life: ", pos=(700,297),
                                         size=(50,50), style=wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW, name='transparenttext')
                eollbl.SetFont(f1)
                self.eoltbx = wx.TextCtrl(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, value=self.n_el, pos=(840, 297), size=(180,25))
                if self.b==1:
                    b3a = wx.Bitmap("button3 a.png")
                    b3b = wx.Bitmap("button3 b.png")
                    b4a = wx.Bitmap("button4 a.png")
                    b4b = wx.Bitmap("button4 b.png")
                    dtbbtnc = btn.GenBitmapButton(panel, wx.ID_ANY, bitmap=b3a, pos=(700,330),  style=wx.NO_BORDER|wx.BU_EXACTFIT,size=(147, 62))
                    dtbbtnc.SetBitmapSelected(b3b)
                    dtbbtnc.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.cc)
                    dtbbtnd = btn.GenBitmapButton(panel, wx.ID_ANY, bitmap=b4a, pos=(880,330),  style=wx.NO_BORDER|wx.BU_EXACTFIT,size=(147, 62))
                    dtbbtnd.SetBitmapSelected(b4b)
                    dtbbtnd.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.cls2)
                    self.Show()
                else:
                    b8a = wx.Bitmap("button8 a.png")
                    b8b = wx.Bitmap("button8 b.png")
                    b4a = wx.Bitmap("button4 a.png")
                    b4b = wx.Bitmap("button4 b.png")
                    dtbbtnc = btn.GenBitmapButton(panel, wx.ID_ANY, bitmap=b8a, pos=(880,330),  style=wx.NO_BORDER|wx.BU_EXACTFIT,size=(147, 62))
                    dtbbtnc.SetBitmapSelected(b8b)
                    dtbbtnc.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.cc)
                    dtbbtnd = btn.GenBitmapButton(panel, wx.ID_ANY, bitmap=b4a, pos=(700,330),  style=wx.NO_BORDER|wx.BU_EXACTFIT,size=(147, 62))
                    dtbbtnd.SetBitmapSelected(b4b)
                    dtbbtnd.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.cls)
                    self.Show()
                if t-1==self.n or t==1:
                    self.b=1
                if moddtb.IsShown(self)==False:
                    break               
            self.n+=1
    def cls2(self, event):
        frame = dspdtb()
        self.Destroy()  
    def cls(self, event):
        nf = MainPage()
        nf.Show()
        self.Destroy()
    def cc(self, event):
        cr_a = self.hntbx.GetValue()
        print ("Value: \"",cr_a,"\"")
        if cr_a != None or cr_a !="" or cr_a !=" " or cr_a !="  " :
            id = self.n_id
            ip = self.n_ip
            cr_b = self.roletbx.GetValue()
            cr_c = self.athtbx.GetValue()
            cr_d = self.alstbx.GetValue()
            cr_e = self.typtbx.GetValue()
            cr_f = self.envtbx.GetValue()
            cr_g = self.isiptbx.GetValue()
            cr_h = self.staiptbx.GetValue()
            cr_i = self.vliptbx.GetValue()
            cr_j = self.pubiptbx.GetValue()
            cr_k = self.grpiptbx.GetValue()
            cr_l = self.idriptbx.GetValue()
            cr_m = self.syssztbx.GetValue()
            cr_n = self.appsztbx.GetValue()
            cr_o = self.dtsztbx.GetValue()
            cr_p = self.physztbx.GetValue()
            cr_q = self.rdcontbx.GetValue()
            cr_r = self.lgmemsztbx.GetValue()
            cr_s = self.phymemsztbx.GetValue()
            cr_t = self.mdltbx.GetValue()
            cr_u = self.srlnumtbx.GetValue()
            cr_v = self.prvcputbx.GetValue()
            cr_w = self.ostbx.GetValue()
            cr_x = self.wrtytbx.GetValue()
            cr_y = self.eostbx.GetValue()
            cr_z = self.eoltbx.GetValue()
            mycursor.execute("UPDATE ip_config SET host_name=%s, role=%s, authorize=%s, alias=%s, type=%s, enviroment=%s, isci_ip=%s, static_ip=%s, vlan=%s, public_ip=%s, group_ip=%s, idrac_ip=%s, system_size=%s, application_size=%s, data_size=%s, physical_size=%s, raid_config=%s, logical_mem=%s, physical_mem=%s, model=%s, serial_number=%s, `processor/vcpu`=%s, os=%s, warranty=%s, end_of_support=%s, end_of_life=%s WHERE id=%s;", (cr_a, cr_b, cr_c, cr_d, cr_e, cr_f, cr_g, cr_h, cr_i, cr_j, cr_k, cr_l, cr_m, cr_n, cr_o, cr_p, cr_q, cr_r, cr_s, cr_t, cr_u, cr_v, cr_w, cr_x, cr_y, cr_z, id))
            if self.b==1:
                LoadThread()
                loada = load()
                loada.ShowModal()
                wx.MessageBox('A new connection has been created, ', 'Connection Created', wx.OK)
            frame = MainPage()
            self.Destroy()      
        else:
            wx.MessageBox('An error has been made, please fill out the host name before you continue...', 'Creation Error', wx.OK | wx.ICON_ERROR)
            frame = MainPage()
            self.Destroy()
```

The problem with this module however are two things:

1. If I run this program, an infinite loop happens, which results to a never ending cycle of opened windows.
2. Even without the weird infinite loop problem, if I fixed it with only the first loop in mind, then it'll just display all the windows at once instead of displaying them one by one. Creating confusion within the program.

Is there a way to display the modification windows one by one per row without having to display them all at once?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your app needs a lot of restructuring. People are more likely to help you if you create a minimal working example that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve what you want is to show each configuration window as a modal window, just like the window you get when searching for a file (`wx.FileDialog`).

See the code (and the comments) below for one way to do this.

The problem with the code is that it works perfectly only in Windows. In macOS and Linux the main window is not perfectly disabled. For example, in macOS you cannot minimize and maximize the main window but you can interact with the buttons; in Linux you cannot interact with the buttons but you can minimize and maximize the window. Thus, depending on the platforms you want to support you will need to tweek the code a little bit.

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """
    Main Window of the App
    """
    def __init__(self):
        title='Multiple consecutive windows (ShowModal way)'
        super().__init__(None, title=title)

        #### Variables
        # Number of configuration windows that will be created
        self.WinNum = 5
        #### Widgets
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.buttonShow = wx.Button(self.panel, pos=(50, 50), label='ShowModal')
        self.buttonTest = wx.Button(self.panel, pos=(50, 100), label='Test')
        #### Bind
        self.buttonShow.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.ShowWindows)
        #### Position of the window
        self.SetPosition(pt=(50, 50))

    def ShowWindows(self, event):
        """
        This will create the configuration windows as modal windows. 
        """
        i = 0
        # This is to show a way to pass information from the configuration
        # windows to the main window. Just in case.
        self.configResults = []

        #### Depending of the OS you want to support you will need to modify the
        #### this window as explained in the answer. For macOS at least the 
        #### ShowModal button must be disable to avoid launching parallel 
        #### configuration windows. Remove the comment in the line below
        #self.buttonShow.Disable()

        while i < self.WinNum:
            a = WinModal(i)
            a.ShowModal()
            i += 1

        #### After all windows are closed the button must be enable again in
        #### macOS. Remove the comment in the line below.
        #self.buttonShow.Enable()

        #### Check that the information was passed 
        print(self.configResults)

class WinModal(wx.Frame):
    """
    Configuration window
    """ 
    def __init__(self, ThisWinNum):
        title = 'This is window number: ' + str(ThisWinNum)
        super().__init__(None, title=title)
        #### Variables
        self.ThisWinNum = ThisWinNum
        # To append Cancel when closing the configuration window without 
        # clicking Ok
        self.cancel = True
        #### Widgets
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.buttonOk = wx.Button(self.panel, pos=(50, 50), label='Ok')
        #### Positions
        self.SetPosition(pt=(200, 200))
        #### Bind
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnClose)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onOk)

    def ShowModal(self):
        """
        This function is the one giving the wx.FileDialog behavior
        """
        self._disabler = wx.WindowDisabler(self)
        self.Show()
        self.eventLoop = wx.GUIEventLoop()
        self.eventLoop.Run()

    def OnClose(self, event):
        """
        To handle closing the windows because you need to exit the eventLoop
        of the modal window.
        """
        if self.cancel:
            frame.configResults.append('Cancel')
        else:
            pass

        del self._disabler
        self.eventLoop.Exit()
        self.Destroy()

    def onOk(self, event):
        """ 
        Do your configuration and exit by calling self.OnClose. You will need 
        something similar if you place a Cancel button in the configuration 
        windows.
        """
        print(self.ThisWinNum)
        # Pass the informartion to the main window
        frame.configResults.append(self.ThisWinNum)
        # To avoid append when Ok is clicked
        self.cancel = False
        self.OnClose(event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
else:
    pass
```